# ClientError: Unable to parse value of "$tweetId=undefined". Please quote string values

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, sanity

I am using sanity, also if you need more information I will provide it as soon as possible.
When I go to `http://localhost:3000/api/getComments` it writes me that error:

> ClientError: Unable to parse value of "$tweetId=undefined". Please
> quote string values.

**fetchComments.ts**

```js
import { Comment } from "../typings"

export const fetchComments = async (tweetId: string) => {
     const res = await fetch(`/api/getComments?tweetId=${tweetId}`)

     const comments: Comment[] = await res.json()

     return comments
}
```

**getComments.ts**

```js
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { groq } from "next-sanity";
import { sanityClient } from "../../sanitytwitter/sanity";
import { Comment } from "../../typings";

const commentQuery = groq`
*[_type == "comment" && references(*[_type == 'tweet' && _id == $tweetId]._id )]
{
    _id,
    ...
} | order(_createdAt desc)
`

type Data = Comment[]

export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
    const { tweetId } = req.query;

    const comments: Comment[] = await sanityClient.fetch(commentQuery, {
        tweetId,
    })

    res.status(200).json(comments)
}
```

Comment: If you log `req.query.tweetId` to the console in the `getComments` API route, does it have the expected value?

Answer (score 0):

```
const res = await fetch(`/api/getComment?tweetId=${tweetId}`);
```

not

```
const res = await fetch(`/api/getComments?tweetId=${tweetId}`);
```

its just a typo "getComment" not "getComments"

Comment: OP states that the API route is at `/pages/api/getComments.ts`, it's not a typo in the URL. He can even access `localhost:3000/api/getComments` further confirming the URL is the correct one.